# ssrs header for list which is repeating after page breaks

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services

I have a layout for report services and subreports. My subreports are lists with headers. I need to get header for each subreport on pagebreaks. I've tried to use a table for this task but I didn't manage them to display headers on pagebraks though I was using repeat on each page or something like this and others (I'm really frustrated about whole of a lot those properties for silly task and not working). Maybe someone can suggest solution for this task without using a table? I've found solution to use header of subreport for this but this didn't work out as well.

I tried to Set "Repeat header rows on each page", "Repeat header columns on each row" and tried to set "RepeatOnNewPage" property of the header in the Advanced mode but everything was futile. All these things I tried to use even for a simple table without lists.

The report is rendered to PDF... maybe this repeating headers feature doesn't work for PDF?

Comment: Did you try `RepeatRowHeaders` property for tablix item?

Comment: Tables are the best thing for repeating headers. You could however use a list if you want each item to have a header. If you only want a header at the top of the page you could make the rectangle the same size of the page and force it to show a single item on each page, if an item's content exceeds the length of the page, it'll go to the next page. but won't repeat teh header there.

Comment: What exactly is your desired output?  do you wan tot use a Subreport?  It sounds to me like a table would be best for what you require....?

Comment: Google says that RepeatRowHeaders is the property of tablix from the object model of the reporting services... Can I get it somehow from the UI? Isn't it's the same with "Repeat header rows on each page"?

Comment: What I'm trying to make is the list of object models. Not sure that it will workout with table if put list in one cell which is stretched out to several pages...

Comment: Oceans, how can I force rectangle to be shown on each page? I've tried to use header but this didn't work out when I put subreport into layout.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. The problem was that I've been adding rows to table outside of the group (the first row is marked with three horizontal lines at the row pane). After I added lines inside of this group - the header started to display after the page break.

As for lists... I found out that one can use table as list... If one adds source of data to the row then it will be multiplied if several data sets provided.